# If a df does not have all the cols in another, add them and set all to 0

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 data frames e.g.

```
# empty df
df1 <- data_frame(
  x = 1,
  y = 1,
  z = 1
) |> 
  filter(x < 1)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  a = 1:10,
  c = letters[1:10]
)
```

df2 does not contain columns y and z yet they exist in df1. I would like to mutate the columns that are non existent in df2 from df1 onto df2 so that I have a df that looks like this:

```
df_full
    x  a c y z
1   1  1 a 0 0
2   2  2 b 0 0
3   3  3 c 0 0
4   4  4 d 0 0
5   5  5 e 0 0
6   6  6 f 0 0
7   7  7 g 0 0
8   8  8 h 0 0
9   9  9 i 0 0
10 10 10 j 0 0
```

How can I use r/dplyr to add any columns from df1 that don't exist in df2 and just set them all to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, use `bind_rows` and replace with 0

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df2, df1) %>% 
   mutate(across(where(~ all(is.na(.x))), ~ 0))
```

-output

```
    x  a c y z
1   1  1 a 0 0
2   2  2 b 0 0
3   3  3 c 0 0
4   4  4 d 0 0
5   5  5 e 0 0
6   6  6 f 0 0
7   7  7 g 0 0
8   8  8 h 0 0
9   9  9 i 0 0
10 10 10 j 0 0
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df2[setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))] <- 0
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `power_left_join` from the `powerjoin` library, with `fill = 0`.

```r
library(powerjoin)

power_left_join(df2, df1, fill = 0)

    x  a c y z
1   1  1 a 0 0
2   2  2 b 0 0
3   3  3 c 0 0
4   4  4 d 0 0
5   5  5 e 0 0
6   6  6 f 0 0
7   7  7 g 0 0
8   8  8 h 0 0
9   9  9 i 0 0
10 10 10 j 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `left_join` your dataframes and `replace_na` to 0 `across` the `columnnames` of df1 with `!!` you need like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 |>
  left_join(df1) |>
  mutate(across(!!colnames(df1), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(x)`
#>     x  a c y z
#> 1   1  1 a 0 0
#> 2   2  2 b 0 0
#> 3   3  3 c 0 0
#> 4   4  4 d 0 0
#> 5   5  5 e 0 0
#> 6   6  6 f 0 0
#> 7   7  7 g 0 0
#> 8   8  8 h 0 0
#> 9   9  9 i 0 0
#> 10 10 10 j 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A base R option with `merge`

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE),
    \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
  )
)
```

gives

```
    x y z  a c
1   1 0 0  1 a
2   2 0 0  2 b
3   3 0 0  3 c
4   4 0 0  4 d
5   5 0 0  5 e
6   6 0 0  6 f
7   7 0 0  7 g
8   8 0 0  8 h
9   9 0 0  9 i
10 10 0 0 10 j
```